# kendoMenu() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-menu

kendoMenu() is not a function , Other functions like kendobutton   and         kendotabstrip are  working but kendoMenu is not working.Please give     solution for this, Is there is any JS or CSS file is missing from this code?

I have following html:-

```
<link href="~/Content/Styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<link href="~/Content/Styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="~/Content/Styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="~/Scripts/kendojs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendojs/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
    <div id="megaStore">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>
                Products
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Furniture
                        <ul> 
                            <li>Tables & Chairs</li>
                            <li>Sofas</li>
                            <li>Occasional Furniture</li>
                            <li>Children's Furniture</li>
                            <li>Beds</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                            
                </ul>
            </li>
       </ul>
<script>         
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").kendoMenu();
  });
</script>
```

DEMO : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/index

Comment: no error for me using this `<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed some Css or JS

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

above CSS / Js are needed for display the menu,

for more information please find this link,

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/right-to-left-support